# Java JPA repository and polymorphism

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism, spring-data-jpa

I have following object model and repository in my application:

```
@Entity
class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {}
class Truck extends Vehicle {}

@Repository
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {}
```

What I'm trying to get working is following:

```
Vehicle t = new Truck();
VehicleRepository r = new VehicleRepository();
r.save(t);
```

How to get this code working without need of copying Truck to Vehicle object?

Thanks!

Comment: By creating a TruckRepository?

Comment: I don't need to persist Tuck or Car specific data.

Comment: Vehicle t = new Truck();

Comment: Exactly this is not working with JPA: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: foo.bar.Truck

Comment: Read up on some basics: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: JPA has no such "Repository". Spring Data JPA does, which is a different API

Comment: @NeilStockton you are right, my mistake in the description. JPARepository Interface I'm extending is a Spring's one. But, at the end, the exception is caused by org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist method.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan Hay linked to you, you need to set up the inheritance :

1. Add @Entity to all classes
2. Add @Inheritance to your Vehicle class to enable inheritance for the entityManager, If you're not supposed to store any raw Vehicle, you can use @MappedSuperClass

For the rest i relink the link that Alan Hay provided : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want to achieve. I do not want to persist Truck and Car and expose those to Entity Manager, but only Vehicle data.

Comment: Then use a copy constructor to transform anything that inherits from Vehicle to Vehicle. However when you will query the Vehicle in database, you'll get Vehicle, not Truck neither Car so i don't really the point of doing this.... Or you can add @Transient to any field from your subclasses you don't want to be stored.

Comment: Thank you, this one works fine. But the question of this post is to find a way without having to copy the data to Vehicle object.

Comment: You just copy the data inherited from Vehicle to a new Vehicle, you're not copying others data. Isn't this what you want ?

Comment: actually, I want to store a Vehicle as a Vehicle, regardless of the concrete class behind it. This can be achieved by copying the data to the Vehicle class, but I've a feeling, I just missing an annotation or configuration setting.

Comment: Nope you're not missing anything as far as i know this is the only way.